# Nodejs The "listener" argument must be of type function

Tags: node.js, events

i am trying to use event handlers and want to make a online and offline function, but I get this error message: The "listener" argument must be of type function.

Can anyone explain why it happens?

app.js

```
'use strict';

const events = require('events');

const eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

const checkStatus = require('./connection');

const connectionData = checkStatus({
    host: 'www.google.de',
    port: 443
}, (err, content) => {

    if(err) {
        return console.log(err.message);
    }

    console.log(content);

});

eventEmitter.on('status', connectionData);
```

connection.js

```
'use strict';

const needle = require('needle');
const events = require('events');
const eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
const checkStatus = (options, callback) => {

    needle.get(`https://${options.host}:${options.port}`, (err, content) => {

        if(err) {
            return console.log(err.message);
        }
        eventEmitter.emit('status');

        callback(null, 'Content Success');

    });

}

module.exports = checkStatus;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In connection.js your function `checkStatus = (options, callback) => {...}` does not return a function which should've then be passed as the listener `connectionData`  to  `eventEmitter.on('status', connectionData)`.

To fix this try converting `connectionData` to a function

```js
// ...
// converted your code to occur inside a function

const connectionData = () => {
    checkStatus({
        host: 'www.google.de',
        port: 443
    }, (err, content) => {

        if (err) {
            return console.log(err.message);
        }

        console.log(content);

    })
};

eventEmitter.on('status', connectionData);
```